# USING для нескольких таблиц сразу

Tags: sql

Подскажите, есть ли возможность в случаях соединения нескольких таблиц по ключевым полям (например id) без доп. условий пользоваться USING'ом, прописывая его только один раз?

То есть, вместо:

SELECT *
FROM student JOIN attempt USING(student_id)
JOIN subject USING(subject_id)

Хочется написать что-то вроде (т.к. когда таблиц становится много, постоянно прописывать одно и то же несколько утомительно):

SELECT *
FROM student JOIN attempt JOIN subject USING(student_id,subject_id)

Сейчас имею дело с MySQL, но вопрос скорее вне привязки к конкретной СУБД: в целом, такой синтаксис где-либо имеет место?

Comment: *Хочется написать что-то вроде* Нет такого синтаксиса. Но если имена полей спланированы правильно, то работает NATURAL JOIN. Которому ON clause в принципе не нужен.

Comment: Спасибо! Почитаю про NATURAL JOIN